How to calculate the probability of having disjoint paths for n random pairs in an a×b grid graph?
Given a grid graph of $a \times b$ vertices, and randomly choose $n$ pair of vertices ($v_i,u_i$). What is the probability that $n$ node disjoint paths exist that connect these $n$ pairs of vertices?
Another question is to find the expected minimal number of "layers" needed to accommodate node disjoint paths for all $n$ pairs, wherein the paths for each layer cannot intersect with each other.
Given the combinatorial nature of the problem, I understand that this likely does not have a simple closed-form solution. I would appreciate any suggestions on approximation algorithms, relevant theoretical approaches, or references to existing literature that deal with similar problems.

What are you looking for?  An asymptotic expression for this probability?  An algorithm to compute this probability exactly, for given $a,b$ and random vertex-pairs; or for given $a,b$ and given vertex-pairs?  An algorithm to compute these paths if they exist?  Something else?
